# Android : Update Image in GridView on touch event in Adapter

Tags: java, android, image, gridview, invalidation

I have a `GridView` and attached adapter to it. Adapter populates images in the grid. I have set `setOnTouchLister` to `GridView` in my `Activity` and implemented in the adapter only. In adapter I have an `Integer[] imageIDs` that contains resource ids of all images that are added & an `ArrayList<ImageSourceObject> imgObjsArr` that extends `ImageView` & has other properties set.

Now `onTouch()`, I want to change the image of the selected image to other one. Here's my code :
SEtting adapter of grid in `Activity` in `onCreate` :

```
        // Set Objects in Game View
    gameView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.game_gridView);
    gameObjAdapter = new GameObjectsAdapter(this, R.id.game_gridView, null);
    gameView.setAdapter(gameObjAdapter);
```

ADAPTER :

```
public class GameObjectsAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnTouchListener {
    super();
    mContext = c;
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    objects = data;
    gridViewResAdap = (GridView) mContext.findViewById(this.layoutResourceId);
    createObjectsArray();
    Log.d("GOA", "Created Objects Array");
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageSourceObject imgView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        imgView = new ImageSourceObject(mContext);
        imgView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(20, 20));
        imgView.getScaleType();
        imgView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imgView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        imgView = (ImageSourceObject) convertView;
    }

    // Chk status of touched of imgView & set image accordingly
    if (imgView.isTouched())
        imgView.setImage(R.drawable.droid_touched2);
    else 
        imgView.setImage(imageIds[position]);

    return imgView;
}   

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int action = event.getActionMasked();
    float currentXPos = event.getX();
    float currentYPos = event.getY();
    int position = gridViewResAdap.pointToPosition((int)currentXPos, (int) currentYPos);

    // Key was Pressed Here
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (position > 0) {
            // Get the object which is clicked
            ImageSourceObject isb = this.imgObjsArr.get(position);
            Log.d("GA", " Postion ID " + isb.getId() + " [] ID : " + imageIds[position]);

            // Change the status of touched & set image
            isb.setTouched(true);
            isb.setImage(R.drawable.droid_touched2); 

            // Update the ArrayList & Integer[] with this updated obj 
            this.imgObjsArr.set(position, isb);
            imageIds[position] = R.drawable.droid_touched2;
            Log.d("ISB", "++++ Object ID : " + isb.getId() + " [] ID : " + imageIds[position] + " ISB Touched :" + isb.isTouched());

            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Postion Pressed : " + (position+1), 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //this.gridViewResAdap.invalidate();
        }

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Logs :

```
02-19 15:19:11.615: D/GA(2046):  Postion ID 2130837556 [] ID : 2130837556
02-19 15:19:11.617: D/ISB(2046): ++++ Object ID : 2130837559 [] ID : 2130837559 ISB Touched :true
```

The logs say that the object in `Integer[]` & `ArrayList` both are updated & have right values. After all this also the image is not updated on the screen. The `gridViewResAdap` is also the object of grid that is passed from the activity. I tried calling `invalidate()` on it also, but yet no results. As in my `getView()`, I am using `imageIDs`, so I have kept that also updated.

ImageSourceObject :

```
public class ImageSourceObject extends ImageView {

public void setImage(int resourceId) {
    super.setImageResource(resourceId);
    this.setId(resourceId);
}
```

Also, `onTouch()` gives error to call `onPerformClick()`, I am not sure where to call & why to call. I have alos not implemented `onClickListener` in the adapter. What can be done in this case & what to write in `onClickListener` when things are manged in `onTouch()`.

Can you help me know why the image object is not updating and where am I going wrong ? I thought I have to refresh the grid, so have also called invalidate(), but no results.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try to add this.notifyDataSetChanged(); after yout Toast in onTouch()

Comment: usually you don't want to handle on click/touch listeners inside adapter class, rather do it in activity -> update array that you pass into adapter and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Yes Mark, but I have 2 gridview's in the same Activity & different Adapters. Hence implemented in respective Adapters. And both gridview's contains images only from list of resources.

Comment: It is not a reason to implements the OnTouchListener inside the adapter. You could define two implementations of OnTouchListener separately , or use the same one and check the view ID inside onTouch() to separate the implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your `ImageView` begins handling the TouchEvent, it is the only view allowed to do anything with that touch gesture. You want your `GridView` to intercept the TouchEvent, check the X and Y coordinates of the TouchEvent (`event.getX(); event.getY()`) and see if those coordinates fall within the bounds of one of your `ImageView` objects. If yes, set a flag on the `ImageView` or something that can trigger your `setImageDrawable()` method. I was able to achieve a similar effect in one of my projects but I had to create a custom GridView class (`public class yourGridView extends GridView`), then override the following:

```
@Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch(action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.i(AGL, "InterceptAction = DOWN");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Log.i(AGL, "InterceptAction = MOVE");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                Log.i(AGL, "InterceptAction = CANCEL");
                return false;
        }
        return true;  //returning true tells your main Activity that you want the custom GridView to handle this TouchEvent; It will then send the TouchEvent to your GridView's onTouchEvent() method for handling.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch(action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                int xCoord = (int) event.getX();
                int yCoord = (int) event.getY();
                Log.i(AGL, "MOVE EVENT;" + "\n" +  "Touch X = " + Integer.toString(xCoord) + "\n" +
                "Touch Y = " + Integer.toString(yCoord));
                for(int i = 0; i < this.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    ImageView suspect = (ImageView) this.getChildAt(i);
                    if(suspect.getBounds().contains(xCoord, yCoord)) {
                        suspect.CHANGE_YOUR_IMAGE_HERE();
                        suspect.invalidate();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

PLEASE NOTE: getBounds() is a method I wrote in my custom `ImageView` class. This method returns a Rect object that represents the bounding box of the `ImageView` object. You will have to use your own logic for fetching the bounds of your `ImageView`.

ALSO NOTE: When I run this logic in my project, my `ImageView`s change images rapidly during the touch gesture. I haven't figured out yet how to limit it to one image change per MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

int action = event.getActionMasked();
float currentXPos = event.getX();
float currentYPos = event.getY();
int position = gridViewResAdap.pointToPosition((int)currentXPos, (int) currentYPos);

// Key was Pressed Here
if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
    if (position > 0) {
       ((ImageView)v).setImageDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.droid_touched2));
    }

    return true;
}

return false;
```

}

Comment: But I don't get setImageDrawable of v in the adapter class ??? It gives error - "The method setImageDrawable(Drawable) is undefined for the type View"

Comment: You need to cast it to ImageView. You can see that you get (View v) as parameter inside your onTouch. this is the Image you touched so you can use it directly.

Comment: I had tried that earlier also, tried now alos type casting with ImageSourceObject & ImageView, but it throws error : 02-19 16:32:16.480: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2162): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.GridView cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
I am trypecating like this :-  ImageView iv = (ImageView)v;

Comment: I didn't pay attention that you set your GridView with touchListener and not the cells. So you could try notifydataSetChanged(), but why not use setOnItemClickListener() on your gridView? it will give you the item.

Comment: I thought onTouch is more better than using on ItemClick listener, hence. That's it. No other special reason for he same. Where to call notifydataSetChanged() method ?

Comment: i wrote in comment above, after your Toast.

Comment: Thanks for this, that notify worked. Now from these images I will have few images in another grid (lets say targetsGrid). When user clicks on the image I change the image & that same image needs to be changed in targetsGrid also. Its adapter (TargetsGridAdapter) & different & has no need to implement any listener. From this adapter how can I notify/call TargetsGridAdapter to change the image of this same one ? This adapter has object of Activity, would it be better to call a method of Activity from this adap & that calls targetsAdap method & makes changes. OR some else What would be best ?

Comment: The another GridView is in same Activity as this one?

Comment: Yes, same GameActivity contains & creates this 2 GridViews & it's adapters.

Comment: So you can just to take your mContext, cast it to your GameActivity, find your other adapter and update it data structure, and call it notifyDataSetChanged();